# Modular way to use jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use jQuery selectors in modular way:

```
var logo = $('.logo', function() {
    function show () {
        console.log('logo has appeared');
        $(this).addClass('logo-animated');
    };

    function hide() {
        console.log('logo has been removed');
    };
});
```

I want to be able to assign selector to variable and have some functions within it that I could be able access from outer it's scope.

**NOTICE**, that is pseudo code, I just drew you a picture of how I see it.

```
var selector = $('.someclass',
    # here goes functions that I could access from outside;
);
```

**UPDATE**

```
var parallax = function() {

    var images = ["http://localhost:8000/static/assets/images/hero-image-welcome.jpeg"];

    var selector =  $('.parallax-module');

    var reload = function() {
        console.log('reload')
    };

    $(selector).each(function(index) {
        var image = {};
        image.element = $(this);
        image.height = image.element.height();
        images.push(image);
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
    });

    return {
        images: images,
        reload: reload()
    }

}();

parallax.reload;
console.log(parallax.images[0])

// This goes without error, but isn't right;
var sParallax = $('.parallax-module');
sParallax.addClass('someClass');

// This would cause error;
parallax.addClass('someClass');
```

In this case I can use parallax public properties and methods, but I can't use selector (as I did in the beginning) without creating a new link to it. I know I can use public properties to access selector, but it's not the way I looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the way, but it does not look right to me, it is working thought:

```
var parallax = function() {

    var images = ["http://localhost:8000/static/assets/images/hero-image-welcome.jpeg"];

    var selector =  $('.parallax-module');

    var reload = function() {
        console.log('reload')
    };

    $(selector).each(function(index) {
        var image = {};
        image.element = $(this);
        image.height = image.element.height();
        images.push(image);
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
    });

    return {
        images: images,
        reload: reload()
    }

}().selector;
```

With `selector` reference in the end it is now valid to use `parallax` variable as simple link to DOM element, as well as to access functions that within it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the variable with your desired selector and then just add functions to that variable

```
var logo = $('.logo');
logo.show = function () {
  console.log('logo has appeared');
  $(this).addClass('logo-animated');
}

logo.hide = function () {
  console.log('logo has been removed');
}

logo.show();
logo.hide();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kjt3yunz/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I know that. The question was about the modular way to do it.

Comment: In general, yes and I did that too, but how you access selector out of the scope by $(logo) or by variable `logo` itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm just getting confused. So since you are creating a module you are trying to prevent access to the variable(selector) from the outside. So if you want to do anything with that selector you need to create a function to do it. Maybe if you use an example we could get on the same page and I can be more helpful.

Comment: No, I WANT to access both selector '.logo' and functions that related to it from outside. See the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

You can access through this:

```
 logo.prevObject[0].show()//or hide()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using any others functions: `$(logo).show` or something like that.

Comment: You can see that: logo.toSource()

Comment: toSource() is Gecko-only.

Comment: it is enough to check. Also, `logo.prevObject[0].show()` is working chrome, firefox, IE 10 as well as safari

Comment: Have you read the question, I don't need just simple dictionary-module to have functions within it. I need `logo` to be link to DOM element by itself and also have some functions inside to access from outer it's scope.